# change color on hover of SVG as an input element

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have an SVG as a submit button. I would like the SVG to turn button to color blue from a mouse hover. My code below does not seem to work.
HTML

```
<div class="icon-cnt" id="search-icon">
  <input type="image" src="assets/images/search-fill-2.svg" border="0" alt="Submit" id="submit svg-hover"/>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#svg-hover:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Comment: the id attribute must not contain any spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you add svg with `<input type="image">` tag, you can't change its color with CSS. Instead, you have to create svg using `<svg>` tag to change its color with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.svg-hover:hover {
  background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="icon-cnt" id="search-icon">
  <input type="image" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" border="0" alt="Submit" id="submit" class="svg-hover"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should use `<svg>` instead of `<img>` tag. For [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp).
- And you can have only one ID for an element. So `id="submit svg-hover"` this one will create problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ID like a class, ID is one character set without space. You have two solution use a class instead or change de ID. This is a example use "hover" selector with ID changed check.

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<Style>
#svg-hover:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</Style>
</Head>
<Body>
<div class="icon-cnt" id="search-icon">
  <input type="image" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" border="0" alt="Submit" id="svg-hover"/>
</div>
</Body>
</HTML>
```